# How to set input value based on dropdown selection and function return in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a form that has two field - Type and Number. For every type there is a default number but the user could change to any number they want.

So for me, I have to fill in the input with default value according to the type that the user chose from above drop down box.

I've tried couple of ways but could not succeed, may I know what's wrong in my code?

Here is the html file:

```
    <form-field>
        <select [(ngModel)]="type">
            <option *ngFor="let type of types" [value]="type">{{type}}</option>
        </select>
    </form-field>
    <form-field>
        <input type="number" (change)=getNumber(type) [(ngModel)]="number">
    </form-field>
```

Here is the ts file:

```
  public async getNumber(selectedType: string): Promise<number> {
    const listOfType = await this.service.getTypeList();
    for (const type of listOfType) {
      if (type.typeName === selectedType) {
        return type.number;
      }
    }
  }
```

The method `getTypeList()` will return a list of model that consist of type in string and number.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: The issue aside, I wouldn't recommend using variable names `type` and `number` in Typescript. They both are reserved words.

Comment: First, the `(change)` should be bound to your select field, not the input, since you want to change value of input when the value in dropdown changes. Second, the function bound to the `change` event should not return a value, instead it should set  avalue on your model, e.g. `this.number = type.number`.

Comment: @MichaelD Ok I will change to other variable name, thanks!

Comment: @TotallyNewb Is it like this?
`<select [(ngModel)]="type" (change)=getNumber(type)>`

Now the input looks like:
<input type="number" [(ngModel)]="number" value="{{number}}">


And in the function I removed return, change to `Promise<void>` and added this line `this.number = type.number`